# GWT 2.4 version compatibilty with IE11 browser

Tags: internet-explorer-11, gwt-2.4

WE are having a gwt application which was working properly till IE10 versions.
But unfortunately the same application is not running as expecetd in IE11.

Th issue is --->we have a simple login page which takes credentials.This page succesfully gets authenticated in all IE verison till IE10.

We are clueless why the same login pag eis not working in IE11.

I included '' in my hml file.
we are not yet lucky.how to solve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: we got the solution...We upgraded our third party dependency jars(in our case,smartgwt.jar) to latest versions and things started working well...Also we ensured necessary TLS settings are applied in browser settings to get the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you compile the code using Break Point does your compiler is compiling the onclick event of the button use for login because authentication issue is not related to UI i think something is going wrong on back code of button.May be possible the application is not able to find the button id.

Comment: I will check it..I would request QA from onsite to add app.verbose to the defect .Thanks a lot.